# How to add link to node add form

Tags: 7, nodes, navigation

I wanted to add link besides editor in add post form that will linked to some static page in the page or it may be link for just some java-script purpose.

Is there any drupal module available to solve this or please suggest how can I proceed to get this done.

-- Thanks for your time

Comment: What about just adding a block with HTML?

Answer (score 1):

you can add to the node element in a module and call these in your template.
e.g.

```
mymodule_node_view()
{
  $node->mylink = '<a href="">Link</a>';
}
```

Then in the node.tpl.php

```
print $node->mylink;
```

Comment: simple and good solution ;)